# How do not display xterm terminal from remote server to local machine

Tags: remote-server, xterm

I run my code on remote server trough `ssh` and my code execute other scripts through `xterm`. Then the scripts are displayed on my local machine through `xterm`, but I don't want to display these on my local machine.
Is there any method that do not display these terminals on my local machine, even remote server actually run the scripts through `xterm`?

Comment: please add the scripts. if you run gnome-terminal withing the ssh session, it should open on the remote server. 

example: ssh -Y user1@192.168.2.39 "xterm"

will open the xterm on the remote server, but u get a local display via x11 forwarding (ls command will show remote files)

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I changed the sentences more clearly.